DB connection issue using python via VSS in my server
Am unable to connect db using python via vss in my server but am able to connect that db from my local system with my same python code using vss...And while running code in server am not getting error as well in terminal..it will run code and end it and my code is
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import Error
am sensing like mysql connector not connecting db
I have checked all possible cause like code, configeration of mysql, port all are fine but still from code am unable to connect to db but if same code if i run in my local system its running....and previously its working fine in my server but suddenly it started issue...am not getting solution so please assist

The awnser given by Amadreza is spot on for the client side of the problem. Would like to add that the problem could allso be on the mysql host. Usually a mysql server only allows connections from localhost. But the telnet test will allso make that clear.


Ensure that your server has proper network access to the database
server. Test this using tools like ping or telnet on the database
port. For MySQL, it's typically:
telnet [database_host] 3306

Check the mysql.connector Python package is installed and properly
configured on your server. Reinstall it using:
pip install mysql-connector-python


